# 1st column in html source displays 1 row below the other columns

Tags: html, css

I am having a standard html source and have a text with regular `<ol>` list in it that I want to be displayed on the page in 2, 3 or 4 columns for example **(no table to be used)**. When I say in CSS what i want to happen, the text goes into several columns but the 1st column starts 1 row lower than the others. How can I make all columns to be displays on the same starting level? This is the HTML part:

```
<div id="references">   
    <ol>
        <li>Some text</li>
        <li>Some other text</li>
        <li>And again some text</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

This is the CSS part witch is simply copied from the documentation in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-width.asp:

```
#references {
    -webkit-column-width: 30em; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-width: 30em; /* Firefox */
    column-width: 30em;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean display: inline ??

Comment: I tried to add **display:inline** but this will ruin the columns and display them one below the other

Comment: First of all; css columns are not supported in 'older' browsers (V current - 1 mostly), I'd advise you to use floats and percentages. And secondly: what exactly is the problem? How do your lists render and what is wrong with that?

Comment: the problem is the 1st column starts 1 row below the 2nd, 3rd etc.

Comment: Add the following CSS: `#references ol{margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
#references ol{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, so simple and no idea how i didn't thought of that. Thanks very much!

Comment: Up-voting this, as it was the first correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the ol has a margin. You can remove it so all list elements are aligned.

```
ol {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ous9y59w/

Answer (score 0):

You should force the margin-top of the `<ol>` to 0px;

```
#references ol {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5op36op/) link

Answer (score 0):

I think column width is toooooooooo long..
try to reduce that. like under.

```
-webkit-column-width: 15em; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-width: 30px; /* Firefox */
column-width: 30px;
```

Comment: actually i was just making a random example to show what i wanted to ask. I agree it is too long and in the project have made it quite less :)